# Postfix SMTP authenticated can send as anyone

Tags: postfix, smtp, authentication

The server correctly accepts/rejects the logins though dovecot's authentication mechanism, but after that I can pretend to be anyone when sending emails.

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps = texthash:/etc/postfix/permmap
append_at_myorigin=no

smtpd_helo_restrictions =
     permit_mynetworks,
     reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
     reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
     #reject_unknown_helo_hostname,
     permit

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
     permit_sasl_authenticated,
     permit_mynetworks,
     reject_sender_login_mismatch,
#     reject_non_fqdn_sender,
     reject_unknown_sender_domain,
     permit

smtpd_client_restrictions =
     permit_mynetworks,
     permit_sasl_authenticated,
     reject_unauth_pipelining,
     reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
     reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
     permit
```

I use [this site](http://www.logix.cz/michal/devel/smtp-cli/) for testing, because it's convenient and with --verbose shows me the whole communication, except the message body.

This is the communication log, obviously with identifying stuff and password censored

```
> EHLO localhost
[250] 'example.com'
[250] 'PIPELINING'
[250] 'SIZE 104857600'
[250] 'ETRN'
[250] 'AUTH PLAIN LOGIN'
[250] 'ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES'
[250] '8BITMIME'
[250] 'DSN'
AUTH method (PLAIN LOGIN): using LOGIN
> AUTH LOGIN
[334] 'VXNlcm5hbWU6'
> dXNlckFAdmlydHVhbGRvbWFpbkE=
[334] 'UGFzc3dvcmQ6'
> dGhlcGFzc3dvcmQ=
[235] '2.7.0 Authentication successful'
Authentication of userA@virtualdomainA@example.com succeeded
> MAIL FROM: <userB@example.com>
[250] '2.1.0 Ok'
> RCPT TO: <realremote@example.net>
[250] '2.1.5 Ok'
> DATA
[354] 'End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>'
[250] '2.0.0 Ok: queued as 73519140287'
> QUIT
[221] '2.0.0 Bye'
```

The email was indeed sent as if I was userB@example.com

**The second probable problem** we see there, is that it appends it's real domain to the virtual one, even though `append_at_myorigin` should disable it.
The docs weren't much help. They don't even suggest what the lookup-table should resemble. I had to learn that from elsewhere.

Comment: `MAIL FROM` has nothing to do with authentication. I just sets the return path. It's not even the same address the receiver sees in their mail client.

Comment: Ah, I forget about your *second probable problem*. Maybe it was added by `smtpd_sasl_local_domain` parameter :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I can see, your expectation  is user can't send behalf other user because you put [reject_sender_login_mismatch](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch) in `smtpd_sender_restrictions`. Yes, that should work.

Unfortunately, you put *reject_sender_login_mismatch* **after** *permit_sasl_authenticated*. Based on postfix logic, if your client successfully login via SASL, it won't checked against *reject_sender_login_mismatch* because the it successfully pass the restriction *permit_sasl_authenticated*.

The solution is reorder the restrictions [according to the Postfix official documentation](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_sasl_authz).

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = 
    ...other restriction...
    reject_sender_login_mismatch,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    ...other restriction...
```